# Any Good Examples of Facebook Connect (Registration & Login)?

Tags: registration, facebook-connect

What are some exemplary implementations of Facebook Login or Facebook Registration (colloquially called Facebook Connect) using the new OAuth 2.0 requirements? I have searched the Web and don't seem to find any roundups or good examples.

For example, right now ESPN.com does a pretty good job, or CNN.com. What are some others? Where are some good roundups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Groupon:[image: Groupon login]

and Digg's log in is nice as well:[image: Digg login]

They both ask for permission when you click:[image: asking]

And then you click and you are done! I am all for using this whenever possible, Open ID as well.

Here are a few Screen Shots:

So as I am typing up my examples I found a great article on mashable http://mashable.com/2009/01/12/facebook-connect-implementations/

Answer (score 2):

[friend.ly](http://friend.ly) has a ridiculous implementation of Facebook Registration. Their homepage displays a small box containing form fields that have been pre-filled with your information if you're already signed in to Facebook, such as your name, date of birth, photo, home town, etc. All you do is click "Register" and you're in, and it knows who your friends are and everything. I was pretty impressed.

[image: friend.ly]

Comment: Nice! Any idea how Friend.ly did that? I haven't been able to find documentation.

Comment: Duh, it's right at the top here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/. I didn't realize they were using the simplest form of it.